# DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows customisation

Tags: winforms, datagridview

Apologies if this has already been asked but I cant see that it has been.

A Winforms DataGridView has an 'AllowUserToAddRows' property. Is there a way to ensure a new row is only added if certain conditions are met?

For example, I have a DataGridView with two columns, the first is a TextBox column, the second a ComboBox column. The 'AllowUserToAddRows' property is set to true.

However, I wish a new row to be added only if the user has entered a positive number in the TextBox column *and* made a selection from the ComboBox column. Currently a new row is added when anything is entered in the TextBox column, *or* if a selection is made in the ComboBox column.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, there is. It's called [validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-validate-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control).

Comment: Thanks, will look into that.